# Mysql ordering the same column with two parameters

Tags: mysql

I have a column `data` on the table products that has the `data` rows:

```
02/15/2015,
02/18/2015,
02/20/2015,
02/25/2015,
02/26/2015 (in timestamp).
```

How do I to query ordering it following this rule:

- If `data` is less/equal than 02/20/2015 order by data DESC.
- If `data` is less/equal than 02/20/2015 order by data ASC.

The query result should be:

first if

```
02/25/2015
02/26/2015
```

second if

```
02/20/2015
02/18/2015
02/15/2015
```

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far??

Comment: Often I use order by field 1, field 2, but here I got the same field.. So I really don't know what to do. I got nothing done.

Comment: I think you specified the first condition backwards.

Comment: The query is very simple, I have many dates, refering by one specified date I want to order what is upcoming by DESC and what is back by ASC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions in the `order by`.  For your case, you can do:

```
order by (data <= '2015-02-20') desc,
         (case when data >= '2015-02-20' then data end) desc,
         (case when data < '2015-02-20' then data end) asc
```

The first condition puts the older data first.  The second and third do the ordering as you have specified.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you for sharing your knowledgement.